# problem with the installation of g16 with gaussview under Linux

Tags: software, gaussian, software-assistance

I don't know how  to install the g16 with gv under Linux. According to the internet the installation seems to require a file called a tar.gz which I don't find in the g16 folder. I have a lot of files with the extensions `.exe`, `.prm`, `.help` and so on, and some subfolders inside the g16 folder. I have fedora version .

Comment: Please edit your question to show the exact commands you are issuing and the exact errors they produce. Please include this as text, not as an image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All the information you need to install Gaussian and GaussView in your system, you can obtain it from the [Gaussian.com support](https://gaussian.com/techsupport/#install) site.

Installation Instructions:

- [Gaussian 16 source code](https://gaussian.com/g16/g16src_install.pdf)
- [Gaussian 16 UNIX binary](https://gaussian.com/g16/g16bin_install.pdf)
- [GaussView 6 for UNIX](https://gaussian.com/g16/gv_install.pdf)

Also, you can visit the Gaussian Technical support [page](https://gaussian.com/help/).

Comment: I cheked it I keep getting errors like ' no such file or directory " ' invalid operation also  for the seteven command I got invalid command

Comment: @AIme999 do you mean `setenv`?